# Error: Cannot find module 'canvas' - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, chart.js

I'm using [chartjs-node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas) with chartjs to render a graph config as an image, so after installing it I tried the following :

```
import { ChartJSNodeCanvas } from 'chartjs-node-canvas';
const chartCallback = (ChartJS) => {
  ChartJS.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderWidth = 2;
};
const canvasRenderService = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({
  width,
  height,
  chartCallback,
});
```

But I get the following error when I'm creating a new ChartJSNodeCanvas :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'canvas'
at Function.webpackEmptyContext [as resolve] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:131373:10)
at freshRequire (http://localhost:4200/main.js:21530:69)
at new ChartJSNodeCanvas (http://localhost:4200/main.js:21592:50)
at ChartImageService._callee2$ (http://localhost:4200/main.js:127066:39)
at tryCatch (http://localhost:4200/main.js:115133:17)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:115347:22)
at Generator.next (http://localhost:4200/main.js:115185:21)
at http://localhost:4200/main.js:127002:67
at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7278:21)
at __awaiter (http://localhost:4200/main.js:126981:10) {code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', stack: 'Error: Cannot find module 'canvas'
at Fun…ter (http://localhost:4200/main.js:126981:10)', message: 'Cannot find module 'canvas''}
```

I tried to npm install again, npm rebuild, delete package-lock.json... but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

I'm using Angular with Electronjs

Comment: try `npm rebuild` as mentioned by @uminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas, there's the following note:

> **Node JS version**
>
> This is limited by the upstream dependency [canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas).

Therefore, your problem should be solved if you run the following commands:

```
npm install canvas
npm rebuild
```

Comment: `canvas` is an internal dependency on 'chartjs-node-canvas' package right? Why do we need to install as the project's dependency?

Comment: @subodhkalika: Unfortunately I don't know why this is required.

Answer (score 1):

open New terminal and write npm command to install module which is chartjs-node-canvas

```
npm install canvas 
npm install chartjs-node-canvas
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a blank canvas module, it seems to work.

1. Edit `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas": "file:./src/lib/canvas",
    "jsdom": "^21.1.1",
```

2. Create a directory `canvas` in that path and `index.ts/js` with:

```
module.exports = {};
```

2. `npm i`
3. Run the app.

The solution originates [from here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1708#issuecomment-462990288).